# Is It Possible To Write An Image File To Heroku Temporarily?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I understand Heroku uses an ephemeral filesystem, and files are discarded when the dyno is stopped or restarted, and I'm fine with that. I just need to store files temporarily.

My ReactJS app writes a .png image file to the ***/public*** folder - and it works fine locally - but nothing is getting written to Heroku. Is it possible to write image files to Heroku, and if so is there a setting I must configure?

Answer (score 0):

Please check folder permission. It didn't have write permission.

Comment: That's what I had originally thought, but after checking the permissions I see the /public folder is drwx, and the /public/temp folder (where I want to write the image) is also drwx